# Linux TortoiseSVN

Tags: linux, svn, tortoisesvn, archlinux

Can you advise me the best alternative of TortoiseSVN on Linux?

I'm using ArchLinux with openbox.

Very important for me to see changes for merged files when committing/updating to do small corrections if needed.

Comment: Well, there are some [visual clients available](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_Subversion_clients), and that was exactly your question.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

RabbitVCS the TortoiseSVN for Linux

http://rabbitvcs.org/

Comment: Or, for a more direct source, in English (for those who want it): http://rabbitvcs.org/

Comment: Doesnt work on red hat 7 based operating systems. Not support on centos7 :(